# What is the modern name of the geographic location where Joseph (of 12 brothers) grew up?

Tags: genesis, geography, joseph

In [Genesis 37 we read](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2037) that:

> Jacob lived in the land where his father had stayed, the land of Canaan.

This seems a little broad, and perhaps could encompass larges parts of Israel and Syria today.

My question is: **What is the modern name of the geographic location where Joseph (of 12 brothers) grew up?**

Comment: I believe I'm asking about the meaning of the Biblical text in context - (what does the geographic location mean). Could you please reopen the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the brothers were born in the same place - The house of Lavan in Haran,
which was the father of Jacobs wives. 
For more details I advice to to visit the excellent new site
which is partly in English too:
http://hatanakh.com/en/tanach/0.31.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  When you have a minute, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your answer, but rather a standard welcome message.*  That said, the question asked was off-topic, so don't take it as a guide for what kinds of questions are valid here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haran_(biblical_place) Got it!